# Prevent overlapping from rectangles

Tags: java

I'm currently trying to make a small Entity-Relationship-Modell creating tool for Databases. 
To avoid errors I try to don't allow the rectangles to overlap with a other rectangle.

I got most of my code working and it detects almost every collusion but in one case I can still overlap them and I don't know how to fix this error.

The problem is that it will look on only on rectangle not on both. But I really don't know how to intercept that case.

The strange thing to me is that my Debug line

```
System.out.println("still intersects?");
```

never triggers. Can somebody help me out in this error?

[Image to the error in my Colision](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R3eIV.png)

This Function gets triggered every time I move a Rectangle.
The attribute Selected is a Boolean which says me which Rectangle I'm moving.
Then I check on which side its overlapping and revert back to the old position.

```
    boolean Move(Point point) {
    boolean moved = false;
    boolean foundone = false;
    for (ERMRectangle rectangle : Rectangles) {
        if (rectangle.selected) {
            foundone = true;
            moved = true;
            //calculated new Rectangle after Move
            Rectangle Temp = new Rectangle();
            Temp.x = point.x + rectangle.click.x;
            Temp.width = rectangle.position.width;
            Temp.height = rectangle.position.height;
            Temp.y = point.y + rectangle.click.y;
            for (ERMRectangle rectangle2 : Rectangles) {
                if (rectangle != rectangle2 && rectangle2.position.intersects(Temp))//prevent overlapping
                {
                    Rectangle intersection = rectangle2.position.intersection(Temp);

                    if (intersection.height > intersection.width) {

                        Temp.x = rectangle2.position.x - rectangle2.position.width;
                        if (intersection.x != rectangle2.position.x) {
                            Temp.x = rectangle2.position.x + rectangle2.position.width;
                        }

                    } else {
                        Temp.y = rectangle2.position.y - rectangle2.position.height;
                        if (intersection.y != rectangle2.position.y) {
                            Temp.y = rectangle2.position.y + rectangle2.position.height;
                        }

                    }

                }
                if(rectangle != rectangle2 && rectangle2.position.intersects(Temp))
                {
                    System.out.println("still intersects?");
                }
            }

            rectangle.position = Temp;
        }
    }

    return moved;
}
```

*ERMRectangle* class:

```
import java.awt.Rectangle; 

public class ERMRectangle {
    public Rectangle position;
    public boolean selected;
    public Point click;
}
```

Edit: i resolved it by adding one more for loop into my methode which checks if it still interselects the rectangle and reverts both x and y cordinnates.

Comment: What's an ERM? (Enterprise Risk Management?)  What are the objects and methods of ERMRectangle class?  Is that a custom class you've created, or a library obtained from elsewhere?  What is the code at `ERMRectangle.position.intersects()`?

Comment: its from the libary java.awt.Rectangle

Comment: @DamianGalli Take a look at my solution, and let me know the outcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If at any moment, there will only be one rectangle moving (dragged by the user) there is no need to use nested loops to check for collision n-square times.

All you need is a method like this in your ERMRectangle class:

*These codes assume your ERMRectangle class extends Rectangle class from Java*

```
public boolean isColliding(ArrayList<ERMRectangle> rects)
{
    for(ERMRectangle r : rects)
        if(this != r && this.intersects(r))
            return true;
    return false;
}
```

You can then invoke `isColliding()` in the `mouseReleased(MouseEvent e)` in the mouse listener for your rectangles, and trigger the necessary actions when collision is detected. So, upon every mouse release after dragging, it will check for collisions on the rectangle which you have just moved.

To check for collision as you drag, place the similar codes as you would in `mouseReleased(MouseEvent e)` into `mouseDragged(MouseEvent e)`. This will do a real-time collision detection check as you drag the rectangle.

Comment: i had this before but my problem was, that the mouseDragged event doesnt call on every pixel and that a Rectangle can stuck on a other because it skips the call on the edge

Comment: @DamianGalli Yes, it won't check on every pixel. There is a delay between each check. In that case, you can check upon mouse release. Or you still want to do a real time checking?

Comment: @DamianGalli Why do you want real time checking? Shouldn't a user be able to drag the rectangle wherever they need to *while* moving it? Isn't it only the *final* position that matters? Checking on all the intermediate moves just sounds like it would be a hassle for the user without any real benefit.

Comment: will it dont gaves this big of a adventage, exctually your idea will work too. But i think it's a little benefit even if its not this big of a improvment

Comment: @DamianGalli If just checking at the end will work, then checking on each movement will probably be an enormous hassle to the end user. Imagine trying to drag one rectangle to the other side of the screen when the middle is full of rectangles. I could see triggering a *warning* when the user pauses (or maybe even a warning on each move if it makes it easier to implement), but actually restricting each move would probably just be annoying. Better to only restrict it on release.